# Is there a drush command to set permissions to true on ALL modules for administrator?

Tags: users

I'm getting tired of having to go in the backend and click on some new module's permissions so that I can use them...

Is there a drush command to enable permissions to true on ALL modules in on shot?

This happens on some modules and also when creating content types or using beans or new panels.

Answer (score 0):

You need to look this [Permissions API](https://www.drupal.org/node/802272)

```
$ drush help perm-grant
Grant permissions to a role.

Examples:
drush perm-grant --roles="Admin"          Grant all permissions provided by the Node module to the Admin role.
--modules="node"                                                                                              
drush perm-grant --all-modules            Grant all permissions to Admin role.                                
--roles-="Admin"                                                                                              
drush perm-grant --roles="Editor,Copy     Grant "administer nodes" to Editor and Copy Editor roles.           
Editor" --permissions="administer nodes"                                                                      
drush perm-grant --all-roles              Grant "administer nodes" permission to all roles.                   
--permissions="administer nodes"                                                                              


Options:
--all-roles                               Grant the permissions to all defined roles.                     
--roles                                   Comma-separated list of roles to grant permissions to.          
--permissions                             Comma-separated list of permissions to grant to a role or roles.
--modules                                 Comma-separated list of modules providing permissions to grant. 
--all-modules                             Grant all defined permissions to a role or roles.  

$ drush help perm-revoke
Revoke permissions from a role.

Examples:
drush perm-revoke --roles="Admin"         Revoke all permissions provided by the Node module from the Admin role.
--modules="node"                                                                                                 
drush perm-revoke --all-modules           Revoke all permissions from the Admin role.                            
--roles-="Admin"                                                                                                 
drush perm-revoke --roles="Editor,Copy    Revoke "administer nodes" from the Editor and Copy Editor roles.       
Editor" --permissions="administer nodes"                                                                         
drush perm-revoke --all-roles             Revoke "administer nodes" permission from all roles.                   
--permissions="administer nodes"                                                                                 
drush perm-revoke --reset                 Revoke all permissions from all roles.  Requires confirmation, use with
                                           caution.                                                               


Options:
--all-roles                               Revoke the permissions from all defined roles.                        
--roles                                   Comma-separated list of roles to revoke permissions from.             
--permissions                             Comma-separated list of permissions to revoke from a role or roles.   
--modules                                 Comma-separated list of modules providing permissions to revoke.      
--all-modules                             Revoke all defined permissions from a role or roles.                  
--reset                                   Revoke all defined permissions from all roles.  Requires confirmation,
                                           use with caution.
```

Comment: Thank you, but I dont' get it, I'm not a developer...I tried this:  drush perm-grant --all-modules --roles-="Admin" but cant' get it working, what are the exact drush commands for this?

Comment: check drush role-list (Display a list of all roles defined on the system.)